# Paste multiline text as variable in PowerShell not working

Tags: powershell

I am trying to paste some code from MS Docs into PowerShell, the code is for a variable, but when I paste it and hit enter, nothing happens.

Here's the code for the variable:

```
    $site_script = @'
 {
     "$schema": "schema.json",
         "actions": [
             {
                 "verb": "createSPList",
                 "listName": "Customer Tracking",
                 "templateType": 100,
                 "subactions": [
                     {
                         "verb": "SetDescription",
                         "description": "List of Customers and Orders"
                     },
                     {
                         "verb": "addSPField",
                         "fieldType": "Text",
                         "displayName": "Customer Name",
                         "isRequired": false,
                         "addToDefaultView": true
                     },
                     {
                         "verb": "addSPField",
                         "fieldType": "Number",
                         "displayName": "Requisition Total",
                         "addToDefaultView": true,
                         "isRequired": true
                     },
                     {
                         "verb": "addSPField",
                         "fieldType": "User",
                         "displayName": "Contact",
                         "addToDefaultView": true,
                         "isRequired": true
                     },
                     {
                         "verb": "addSPField",
                         "fieldType": "Note",
                         "displayName": "Meeting Notes",
                         "isRequired": false
                     }
                 ]
             }
         ],
             "bindata": { },
     "version": 1
 }
 '@
```

However, when I paste this and hit enter, nothing happens, and the pointer just goes to a new line that looks like this >>, below is a screenshot: 
[image]

Is there something I need to do? (Still new to PowerShell)

Comment: Here-string should be ended with `<newline>'@` but not with `<newline><space>'@`.

Comment: Thanks @PetSerAl, I have been using the code on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/get-started-create-site-design .. what do I need to change exactly?

Comment: Oh I get what you mean, the space thing.. Thank you @PetSerAl

Comment: @PetSerAl Please but your Answer in Answers. Brittany Please Accept that answer when he does

Answer (score 3):

The error in your Code post is that the ending of your final line includes a space.

```
$Test = @'
    Stuff...
 '@ #This is wrong as there is a space before '@

$Test = @'
    Stuff...
'@ #This is correct
```